# Unity is not recognizing a state change In Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to coding so I don't know much but I am making a test project. When i try to jump Unity is not changing the state and therefore not playing the Jumping and falling animation.My other states are working properly (idle and running) but jumping doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && coll.IsTouchingLayers(ground))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 10f);
        state = State.Jumping;
    }
    Stateswitch();
    anim.SetInteger("state", (int)state);
```

Comment: Is the `velocity` and `state` variables getting set?

Comment: Can you try to add more to your code snippet? Is this in `Void Update()` `Input.GetButtonDown()` will not work unless it is. Is this being used by a character? If so try using https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html and you  can check if your character is touching the ground by checking `if (charactercontroller.isGrounded)`

Comment: thanks for the reply I will check to see if it is grounded